# "How to solve Selenium Webdriver path error ?"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I stored it in d Drive and gave loction of webdriver but it gives an error

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102257491&keywords=python%20developer&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this: `driver.get(url)`
not this: `driver.get("url")`

Comment: i tried it but it does not work same error Ibrokhim.Now the code look like:
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_AL&geoId=102257491&keywords=python%20developer&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get(url)

Comment: can you share your error.

Comment: please be careful location of chroidriver and your desktop's chrome version. some chromedrivers not acceptable for local chrome versions.